# WPF MVVM ViewModel containing ViewModels not updating

Tags: wpf, mvvm, view-model-pattern

I'm very new to WPF and MVVM, and it's been causing me a lot of headaches. Due to issues with navigation, I decided to just have all my content visible at once. I thought I would create a new ViewModel (`MainViewModel`) to contain my two other ViewModels (`StudentViewModel` and `AddStudentsViewModel`).

`MainViewModel` contains something like this:

```
private StudentViewModel _studentVM;
private AddStudentsViewModel _addStudentsVM;

public StudentViewModel StudentVM
{
    get { return _studentVM; }
    set
    {
        if (_studentVM != value)
        {
            _studentVM = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("StudentVM");
        }
    }
}
```

(public `AddStudentsViewModel` `AddStudentsVM` exists as well, I'm just trying to keep this short)

I have successfully bound `StudentVM` and `AddStudentsVM` to my main View, as I can programmatically set values during the initialization phase and when debugging, I can see my button clicks are being redirected to the correct methods. It even seems like I am successfully adding students to objects, however my main View isn't reflecting these changes.

Am I missing something in `MainViewModel`? Or is it not possible for a ViewModel to see the changes in any other ViewModels inside it?

Comment: Your post will still be short if you add the part of the View code where binding is located.

Comment: You will need to expose a method on your child view models which allows you to raise `NotifyPropertyChanged()` on those. Then in the methods you can just use an empty string for the property name, which causes a refresh for all bindings in the view from that view model.

Comment: You need to add some more information to your question. Which property are you calling the setter on? How is the view referencing the datacontext? What does the binding in the xaml look like? What you are expecting, and what are you actually getting? Provide this information and you will likely get more concrete answers.

Answer (score 0):

If your view is bound to some property inside `StudentViewModel` through nested navigation into the property `StudentVM` like `StudentVM.Property`, then to reflect changes on `StudentVM.Property` unto your view would require that you notify the view that `StudentVM` (not `StudentVM.Property`) has changed.

So it depends on how you defined your binding and on which property you're raising the `PropertyChanged` event.

Answer (score -1):

A viewmodel which contains two other viewmodels. Just think about it for a second. It's not a good idea.

Anyway, you have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your containing viewmodels as well. Not only in the containing MainViewModel.

Maybe that is the fault?

Comment: What's wrong in the practice of modularizing the functionalities of an application in small classes and compose those classes together? It's what OOP has been created for.

Comment: If you declare this as "not a good idea", at least tell us why. I honestly don't know what's wrong with this.